# Goal Seek for multiple target cells?

Tags: excel, vba

Im doing a DCF analysis and I was wondering if it is possible to do goal seek on multiple targets.

Say I have these combination of variables

```
Sales Volume = 100,200,300,400 (A1:A4)
Price = 100,200,300,400 (B1:B4)
CAPEX = 1000,2000,3000,4000 (C1:C4)
```

First I shall get the cartesian product of these arrays to generate possible combination of variables

```
Sub Cartesianproduct()

Dim array1(1 To 4) As Long
Dim array2(1 To 4) As Long
Dime array3(1 To 4) As Long


i = 1


For i = 1 To 4

array1(i) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "A").Value
array2(i) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "B").Value
array3(i) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "C").Value

Next i


For i = 1 To 4

    For x = 1 To 4

        For y = 1 to 4

              Z = Z + 1
              Worksheets(1).Cells(Z, "F").Value = array1(i)
              Worksheets(1).Cells(Z, "G").Value = array2(x)
              Worksheets(1).Cells(Z, "H").Value = array3(y)
        Next

    Next

Next
```

End Sub

And then I would like to do Goal seek on NPV (will have formula connected in the spreadsheet), by setting target cells according to the cartesian product. So basically the first goal seek will be NPV when Sales Volume = 100, Price = 100 and CAPEX = 1000.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: By your description, you want to execute some function for every combination of values in your arrays. If so, you already did this by nesting `For y=1 To 4` into `For x=1 To 4` into `For i=1 To 4`.

Comment: Have you looked at using the solver? gives a wider range of constraints that you can control - integer, binary etc

Comment: Is there a problem with the combinations? Or is there a problem with the NPV formula?

Answer (score 0):

### Using Data table - first 2 variables

You can try Excel "[Data table feature(MS)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculate-multiple-results-by-using-a-data-table-e95e2487-6ca6-4413-ad12-77542a5ea50b)". Here is a video from [ExcelIsFun Basic Excel Business Analytics #06](https://youtu.be/3komnmHvglc?t=1m11s) explaining how to use the Data table with 2-variables.

You will end up with 4x4 grid of combination of first 2-variables. In picture, table on the left.

### Adding the 3rd variable

Then you can create another table with classic formulas, adding the **3rd variable**. Again this would be on 4x4 grid, with 3rd variable included.

### Results

You will get something like this (for exammple by multiplying everything with everything):
[image]

Comment: urm i believe this wouldnt work because its not a simple multiplication. for example,

Comment: urm i believe this wouldnt work because its not a simple multiplication. for example,

sales volume* price = revenue,

revenue - capex - fixed cost - variable cost - depreciation (based on percentage of capex) etc etc etc

Comment: In the data table, you have Revenue then. How you connect other variables to the model is up to you. For demonstration purposes i used multiplication. There is one flaw with my approach. We only have 4x4 combinations. We need 4x4x4.